# "The file exists" error on vb.net unzip using shell 32

Tags: vb.net

Help please...
I'm having error "The file exists" when i try to unzip a folder.
At first, the code works fine but then i encountered "The file exists"
Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub unzip(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Output As String)
    Dim m_Sc As New Shell32.Shell
    If Directory.Exists(Output) Then
        Directory.Delete(Output)
    End If
    Dim m_Output As Shell32.Folder = m_Sc.NameSpace(Output)
    Dim m_Source As Shell32.Folder = m_Sc.NameSpace(Source)
    m_Output.CopyHere(m_Source.Items, 4)
End Sub
```

I'm using vb.net(3.5) 2008
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I Found the answer of my problem(thanks to stackoverflow)

Problem: When i repeatedly unzip the same file, it creates a copy of the extracted file on the temporary directory. 
If the temp directory has reached its limit(99 copies) then it a causes the error "The file exists".

temp directory location: "C:\Documents and Settings(your user account)\Local Settings\Temp".

You can access them in .net using (My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp) or (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")).

Solution:
Before unziping(extracting) a file, i first delete the previous copy on the temp folder..
Here is my Code for clearing the temporary directory:

```
Sub CleanUpTemporaryFiles()
    Dim m_StrTemporaryDirectory As String = ""

    'Get the Temporary folder directory
    m_StrTemporaryDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")
    If Directory.Exists(m_StrTemporaryDirectory & _
                        "\Temporary Directory 1 for " & _
                        m_ApplicationName & ".zip\") Then

        Dim directory As String = m_StrTemporaryDirectory & _
                                 "\Temporary Directory 1 for " & _
                                  m_ApplicationName & ".zip\" & _
                                  m_ApplicationName

        Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(directory)
        'Loop on all the files
        For Each f In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            'Change the the file attribute to not read only so that it will not get an error deleting the file

            File.SetAttributes(f.ToString, File.GetAttributes(f.ToString) _
                               Xor FileAttributes.ReadOnly Or FileAttributes.Hidden)
            'Delete the file
            File.Delete(f)
        Next

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & _
                                      "\Temporary Directory 1 for " & m_ApplicationName & ".zip") Then

            System.IO.Directory.Delete(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & _
                                       "\Temporary Directory 1 for " & m_ApplicationName & ".zip", True)

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not that good in explaining things but if you have questions or suggestions please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
m_Output.CopyHere(m_Source.Items, 4)
```

what happens if you change it to value 16?

```
m_Output.CopyHere(m_Source.Items, 16)
```

Does it overwrite the file if it already exists?

Comment: i changed it to 16 but then it still prompts error "The file exists".

Comment: I advised the number 16 to try to make it overwrite the already existing file (with same name). The reference info can be found on the link below. I guess its just a case of getting your file actions flag right?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. if i use 16 it shows the dialog "confirm folder replace", but when i click "Yes to all" then it still prompts the error "The file exists" and nothing happens. Anyway thanks Khan, I'll need to double check my codes.